# Why does 'exists' fail for normal queries and not for filtered queries?

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, querydsl

Consider the following two queries :

```
{
  "_source" : false,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "date": {
              "gte": 1460789348000,
              "lte": 1466059748000
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Now consider the following query with `filtered` and `filter` fields added :

```
{
  "_source": false,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "range": {
                "date": {
                  "gte": 1460789348000,
                  "lte": 1466059748000
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Both give the same result and the 1st query without the `filtered` and `filter` fields doesn't result in an error unlike the following query :

```
{
  "_source": false,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "comment"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Error:

```
{
"error": "SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[bi8BrruxR9i_H8-n4Qo9Mg][acct_prop_5][0]: RemoteTransportException[[Battletide][inet[/172.16.0.11:9302]][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[acct_prop_5][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"_source":false,"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"exists":{"field":"comment"}}]}}}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[acct_prop_5] No query registered for [exists]]; }{[JorHtifCSxGrbb3ovGJMWQ][advocacy_insights_p5_v1_00000000_0000][0]: RemoteTransportException[[Caiera][inet[/172.16.0.11:9304]][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[advocacy_insights_p5_v1_00000000_0000][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"_source":false,"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"exists":{"field":"comment"}}]}}}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[advocacy_insights_p5_v1_00000000_0000] No query registered for [exists]]; }{[Tlt3tXF_S9-rEmK9iwSvoA][audience_act_p5_v2_00000000_0000][0]: RemoteTransportException[[Monet St. Croix][inet[/172.16.0.11:9303]][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[audience_act_p5_v2_00000000_0000][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"_source":false,"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"exists":{"field":"comment"}}]}}}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[audience_act_p5_v2_00000000_0000] No query registered for [exists]]; }{[NTpZwKeYRI6l6zHf2BlIFg][audience_act_p5_v3_00000000_0000][0]: SearchParseException[[audience_act_p5_v3_00000000_0000][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"_source":false,"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"exists":{"field":"comment"}}]}}}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[audience_act_p5_v3_00000000_0000] No query registered for [exists]]; }{[NTpZwKeYRI6l6zHf2BlIFg][audience_act_p5_v3_20150601_0000][0]: SearchParseException[[audience_act_p5_v3_20150601_0000][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"_source":false,"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"exists":{"field":"comment"}}]}}}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[audience_act_p5_v3_20150601_0000] No query registered for [exists]]; }{[Tlt3tXF_S9-rEmK9iwSvoA][auth2][0]: RemoteTransportException[[Monet St. Croix][inet[/172.16.0.11:9303]][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[auth2][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"_source":false,"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"exists":{"field":"comment"}}]}}}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[auth2] No query registered for [exists]]; }{[JorHtifCSxGrbb3ovGJMWQ][authors][0]: RemoteTransportException[[Caiera][inet[/172.16.0.11:9304]][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[authors][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"_source":false,"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"exists":{"field":"comment"}}]}}}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[authors] No query registered for [exists]]; }{[bi8BrruxR9i_H8-n4Qo9Mg][bm_content_lifetime_p5_v1_00000000_0000][0]: RemoteTransportException[[Battletide][inet[/172.16.0.11:9302]][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[bm_content_lifetime_p5_v1_00000000_0000][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"_source":false,"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"exists":{"field":"comment"}}]}}}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[bm_content_lifetime_p5_v1_00000000_0000] No query registered for [exists]]; }{[NTpZwKeYRI6l6zHf2BlIFg][bm_content_lifetime_p5_v2_00000000_0000][0]: SearchParseException[[bm_content_lifetime_p5_v2_00000000_0000][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"_source":false,"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"exists":{"field":"comment"}}]}}}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[bm_content_lifetime_p5_v2_00000000_0000] No query registered for [exists]]; }{[bi8BrruxR9i_H8-n4Qo9Mg][bm_content_lifetime_p5_v93_00000000_0000][0]: RemoteTransportException[[Battletide][inet[/172.16.0.11:9302]][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[bm_content_lifetime_p5_v93_00000000_0000][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"_source":false,"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"exists":{"field":"comment"}}]}}}]]]; nested: .........
```

Whereas with the two fields it becomes a correct query:

```
{
  "_source": false,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "exists": {
                "field": "comment"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What is the difference between `range` and `exists` query which allows only one query to be valid without the `filtered` and `filter` fields?

Comment: All your queries run fine without any errors for me. Please add the error message that you're getting against the query executed for more clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably must be using an older version of Elasticsearch [**version < 2.0**] where `exists` is a filter. There is **no** `exists` query which is why you are getting the error message:`No query registered for [exists]`.

Instead you may use:

```
{
   "_source": false,
   "filter": {
      "bool": {
         "must": [
            {
               "exists": {
                  "field": "comment"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Or simply:

```
{
   "_source": false,
   "filter": {
      "exists": {
         "field": "comment"
      }
   }
}
```

From Elasticsearch version 2.0 onwards, the **query** and **filter** objects have been merged together and there exists only **query** object which is capable of doing both the functionalities. Hence you can use `exists` query from version 2.0 onwards.

You can read more about the merge at: [Better query execution coming to Elasticsearch 2.0](https://www.elastic.co/blog/better-query-execution-coming-elasticsearch-2-0)